# difference between files view and project view in netbeans 8

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I cannot find any difference between the views (files vs. projects). In my IDE they give me exavtly the same, even the submenus. So what might be the difference. I use netbeans 8.0.2 for PHP

Answer (score 1):

Can you make a screenshot and post it ?

The differences should be clearly visible.

[image]

Comment: sorry at the moment I don't know how to upload an image here.

Comment: the only differences I see are the lines SourceFiles and Include-Path, and I don't have the nbproject - is that all?

Comment: download newest and reinstall .

Comment: thank you - I have the latest version 8.0.2 and for such a minor problem I don't want to reinstall. I just wanted to understand the differences

Comment: Have you ever created a project ?